# Rails path helpers from another controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've got an action in my `routes.rb` file:

```
post '/deliveries/:id/confirm' => 'deliveries#confirm', :as => 'delivery_confirm'
```

When I'm using a view for the deliveries controller, I can just use the `delivery_confirm_path` helper and all is well with the world.

What I've also got is something adding lines to the delivery, and this sends an AJAX request to the create action in the lines controller.  The response updates the delivery page, and most of it works.

But when I try to use one of the path helpers for deliveries I get back the following error message:

```
No route matches {:controller=>"deliveries", :action=>"confirm"}
```

Is there any reason why I can't use the deliveries path helper from a delivery lines view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the id parameter or you're not calling the post verb.

```
delivery_confirm_path(@delivery)
```

Comment: Ahh simple!  Had a bit of a problem with parentheses that I need to do a bit more digging on.